# Application on OC4J and Application Weblogic

Tags: jsp, weblogic, oracle-adf, oc4j

I have JSP page running on OC4J  and  we want to pass the value from JSP page on OC4J to Oracle ADF page on weblogic server.  Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to pass the parameter as an url parameter. For this the target application must accept the parameter from the url and then work Ruth it.

Timo